# Google Firebase Cloud Message incompatible with Microsoft EDGE?

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging, postman, microsoft-edge

I get the FCM sample code on git: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging

Tested it on Chrome it worked fine, on MS EDGE don't get the message.

Is there any incompatibility?

Printscreen test on Chrome, EDGE and postman results.

[image: FCM]

Postman results, the message_id is empty:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 9215195938054196561,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Which version of MS Edge you are using for testing this issue? As per the documentation. Cloud Messaging is supported from Edge 17. So if you are using any older version then I suggest you to make a test with the latest version of MS Edge browser. Ref: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/environments_js-sdk

Comment: The version is 18, theoretically supposed to work, I have not changed anything in the example code.
I opened a bug task on their git.
Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 / Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18362
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/404
Tks!

Comment: Thanks for letting us know about the status for this issue.